# Plastiq not updating view until second render

Tags: javascript, promise, plastiq

I'm using [Plastiq](http://featurist.co.uk/plastiq) to build a little site.

I have a an event that fires when I click a button.  The event returns a promise, which, when it resolves, updates the model.

The problem I'm having is that the view does not update when the model does.  If I click the button a second time (firing the event again) the view does update.

Here is some code that demonstrates the problem:

```
/** @jsx plastiq.jsx */
var plastiq = require('plastiq');
var http = require('httpism');

class App {
  constructor() {
    this.apiKey = '...';
    this.forecast = {};
  }

  getForecast() {
    return http.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${this.city}&appid=${this.apiKey}`)
    .then((response) => {
      this.forecast = response.body;
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>Weather</h1>
      <input type='text' binding={[this, 'city']} />
      <button onclick={() => { this.getForecast() } }>Get forecast</button>
      <div>
        { this.forecast.wind }
      </div>
    </div>;
  }
}

plastiq.append(document.body, new App());
```

How can I get the view to update the first time the button is clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your click callback should return a promise for plastiq to rerender.

Turn this:

```
onclick={() => { this.getForecast() }}
```

Into this:

```
onclick={() => this.getForecast() }
```